# To Sum Value using linq

Tags: c#, linq

In the below code i have a list i am trying to get values from list using linq query and sum the values.But i don't know how to sum the values.So please help me to resolve the issue.

```
list contains:
Desc Month level value
M1  Jan     L1    2
M1  Jan     L2    6
M2  Feb     L1    4
M2  Feb     L2    1

My Expected Result:
M1 Jan 8
M2 Feb 5



var sums1 = objList

              .GroupBy(y => new { y.Desc, y.Month, y.value })
               .Select(group => new { KeyValue = group.Key, Count = group.Count() });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be including the `value` in your grouping - you want to *group* by just `Desc` and `Month` (I assume), then sum the value parts. Two options:

```
var sums1 = objList
    .GroupBy(y => new { y.Desc, y.Month })
    .Select(group => new { KeyValue = group.Key, Sum = group.Sum(y => y.value) });
```

Or in a single call:

```
var sums1 = objList.GroupBy(
      y => new { y.Desc, y.Month },
      (key, values) => new { key.Desc, key.Month, Sum = values.Sum(y => y.value) });
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `group.Count` with `group.Sum(x=>x.value)`

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ's [Sum()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method for IEnumerable.

```
  .Select(group => new { KeyValue = group.Key, Sum = group.Sum(obj => obj.value)});
```